# XSLT expression to check if variable belongs to set of elements

Tags: xslt

I have code like this:

```
  <xsl:if test="$k='7' or $k = '8' or $k = '9'">
```

Is there any way to put this expression in a form, like, for instance SQL

```
   k IN (7, 8, 9)
```

Ty :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

XSLT / XPath 1.0:

```
<!-- a space-separated list of valid values -->
<xsl:variable name="list" select="'7 8 9'" />

<xsl:if test="
  contains( 
    concat(' ', $list, ' '),
    concat(' ', $k, ' ')
  )
">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('Item ', $k, ' is in the list.')" />
</xsl:if>
```

You can use other separators if needed.

In XSLT / XPath 2.0 you could do something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="list" select="fn:tokenize('7 8 9', '\s+')" />

<xsl:if test="fn:index-of($list, $k)">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('Item ', $k, ' is in the list.')" />
</xsl:if>
```

If you can use document structure to define your list, you could do:

```
<!-- a node-set defining the list of currently valid items -->
<xsl:variable name="list" select="/some/items[1]/item" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="k" select="'7'" />

  <!-- test if item $k is in the list of valid items -->
  <xsl:if test="count($list[@id = $k])">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Item ', $k, ' is in the list.')" />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ty m8. Its overkill for simple scenario like I have but its OK for long lists... I was more hopping that xpath has some form of integrated solution....

Comment: Not XPath 1.0 - when you can't use node-sets to solve your problem you're down to string functions or maybe some extension function. XPath 2.0's sequences make thinks easier in any case.

Answer (score 8):

If your processor supports XPath 2.0, then you can compare `$k` to a sequence like so:

```
<xsl:if test="$k = (7, 8, 9)">
```

You could even use the range-operator in this particular case:

```
<xsl:if test="$k = (7 to 9)">
```

There is no need for an explicit type cast. Tested with Saxon-HE 9.8.0.12N (XSLT 3.0).

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <node>5</node>
    <node>6</node>
    <node>7</node>
    <node>9</node>
    <node>10</node>
    <node>79</node>
    <node>8</node>
</root>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node">
        <xsl:variable name="k" select="text()"/>
        <xsl:if test="$k = (7 to 9)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <node>7</node>
   <node>9</node>
   <node>8</node>
</root>
```

Comment: In my case I did the following `<xsl:if test="$k = ('401', '402')">`. And it worked.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, at least with Saxon, whether you wrap the numbers in quote marks or not. For non-numeric characters you need the quote marks of course.

Comment: In my case, the values that I may have in `$k` may have leading zeroes. In the example I provided that is not represented. So, I am treating my values as strings to avoid un expected behaviours.