# XSLT1.0: Multiple values in choose-when in the right part of equation?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there any way to put more then one value in the right part of equation?

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="Properties/LabeledProperty[Label='Category Code']/Value = 600,605,610">
```

This code above returns:

```
XPath error : Invalid expression
Properties/LabeledProperty[Label='Category Code']/Value = 600,605,610
                                                             ^
compilation error: file adsml2adpay.xsl line 107 element when
```

The reason I don't want to use 'OR' is because there are around 20 numbers should be in the right part for each 'when' test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:config="http://tempuri.org/config"
  exclude-result-prefixes="config"
>
  <config:categories>
    <value>600</value>
    <value>605</value>
    <value>610</value>
  </config:categories>

  <xsl:variable 
    name   = "vCategories" 
    select = "document('')/*/config:categories/value" 
  />

  <xsl:key
    name   = "kPropertyByLabel"
    match  = "Properties/LabeledProperty/Value"
    use    = "../Label"
  />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="key('kPropertyByLabel', 'Category Code') = $vCategories">
        <!-- ... -->
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works because the XPath `=` operator compares every node from the left hand side to every node on the right hand side when working on node sets (comparable to an SQL `INNER JOIN`).

Hence all you need to do is create a node set from your individual values. Using a temporary namespace you can do that right in your XSLT file.

Also note that I've introduced an `<xsl:key>` to make selecting property values by their label more efficient.

---

EDIT: You could also create an external `config.xml` file and do this:

```
<xsl:variable name="vConfig" select="document('config.xml')" /> 

<!-- ... -->

<xsl:when test="key('kPropertyByLabel', 'Category Code') = $vConfig/categories/value">
```

---

With XSLT 2.0 the concept of sequences has been added. It's simpler to do the same thing there:

```
<xsl:when test="key('kPropertyByLabel', 'Category Code') = tokenize('600,605,610', ',')">
```

This means you could easily pass in the string `'600,605,610'` as an external parameter.

Comment: A different approach to doing the same thing can be found in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1007037/18771

Comment: Just a note: if the values are not passed in as a parameter then simply doing `<xsl:when test="key('kPropertyByLabel', 'Category Code') = (600,605,610)">` suffices with XSLT 2.0, then there is no need for tokenize.

Comment: @Martin Absolutely. I just wanted to point out the added usefulness of being able to configure the program instead of having to change the source code when there's a change. (OTOH you could externalize the configuration to an XML document and load that in the XSLT and have almost the same convenience in 1.0)