# Test if parameter is one of several values in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XSLT expression to check if variable belongs to set of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007018/xslt-expression-to-check-if-variable-belongs-to-set-of-elements)

Given a parameter, `$name`, what is a short and clean way to check if its value is equal to one of a finite number of values?

For example, say I wanted to merge the first 3 of these `when` tests because their contents were exactly the same.

```
<choose>
  <when test="$name='Alice'">
  <when test="$name='Bob'">
  <when test="$name='Cindy'">
  <when test="$name='Dave'">
  <otherwise>
```

Something like `test="$name in ['Alice','Bob','Cindy']"`, except actually valid :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 it suffices to use `$name = ('Alice', 'Bob', 'Cindy')`.

Comment: Nice! Love it. So much cleaner than the concat/contains and fn:tokenize/fn:index-of patterns. You should add this as an alternative answer for the duplicate as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1007018/39321

Comment: Be aware that for testing if the value is NOT in the list, you use `not($name = ('Alice', 'Bob', 'Cindy'))`, because the result of `'Alice' != ('Alice', 'Bob', 'Cindy')` is true().

Answer (score 2):

**Use (both in XSLT 1.0 and in XSLT 2.0)**:

```
contains('|Alice|Bob|Cindy|', concat('|', $name, '|'))
```

and, as Martin Honnen already mentioned, **in XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) only, one can simply write**:

```
$name = ($seqOfNames)
```